# Removing inserted numbers from a String in java

Tags: java

Ok, so i have created a program that defines if the inserted word is a palindrome or not. 
But i need help on removing numbers that where to be inserted in the string.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Palindrome
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String reverse = "";
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Type a sentence and press enter: ");
      String input = scan.nextLine();
      // use regex to remove the punctuation and spaces
      String Input = input.replaceAll("\\W", " ");
      System.out.println(Input);

      int length = input.length();

      for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
         reverse = reverse.replaceAll("\\W", "") + input.charAt(i);   
      System.out.println(reverse);

      if (input.equals(reverse))
         System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
      else
        System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not a question. Please try to be specific about exactly what you are asking.

Comment: You'll always endup in `else` part for a input as a `sentence`. YOu are checking the original input with reverse of modified input. Re-check what you want exactly? I don't think you want to check whether a sentence is a palindrome?

Comment: What do you mean this is not specific. Read what i wrote.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd work on the String's char array for palindromes. That'd make the removal of digits straightforward as well (check if a char is within '1' and '9').

Comment: @mtk is right, since `reverse` never equals the straight, since it is reversed... :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove digits, try `input.replaceAll("[0-9]","")`

Comment: You can chain it after replacing the punctuation for spaces:       String Input = input.replaceAll("\\W", " ").replaceAll("[0-9]", "");

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your time. I finally got it working. Didn't know you can another .replaceAll Statement after another. Thank You

Comment: You're welcome. replaceAll returns a string, so you can call any string method on it (including of course replaceAll).

Answer (score 0):

Try this........

```
public class T1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String s = "1234ajhdhols233adfjal"; 

        String[] arr = s.split("\\d");
        String sx = new String();
        for(String x : arr){

            sx = sx+x;
        }

        System.out.println(sx);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1234ajhdhols233adfjal"; 
    String str = s.replaceAll("\\d", "");

    System.out.println(str);
}
```